# Calculate daily parameters from a dataframe with hourly-values in rows and with several columns of interest

Tags: r, data.table, tidyverse, lubridate, plotrix

The dataframe `df1` summarizes water temperature at different depths (`T5m`,`T15m`,`T25m`,`T35m`) for every hour (`Datetime`). As an example of dataframe:

```
df1<- data.frame(Datetime=c("2016-08-12 12:00:00","2016-08-12 13:00:00","2016-08-12 14:00:00","2016-08-12 15:00:00","2016-08-13 12:00:00","2016-08-13 13:00:00","2016-08-13 14:00:00","2016-08-13 15:00:00"),
                    T5m= c(10,20,20,10,10,20,20,10),
                    T15m=c(10,20,10,20,10,20,10,20),
                    T25m=c(20,20,20,30,20,20,20,30),
                    T35m=c(20,20,10,10,20,20,10,10))
df1$Datetime<- as.POSIXct(df1$Datetime, format="%Y-%m-%d %H")
df1

             Datetime T5m T15m T25m T35m
1 2016-08-12 12:00:00  10   10   20   20
2 2016-08-12 13:00:00  20   20   20   20
3 2016-08-12 14:00:00  20   10   20   10
4 2016-08-12 15:00:00  10   20   30   10
5 2016-08-13 12:00:00  10   10   20   20
6 2016-08-13 13:00:00  20   20   20   20
7 2016-08-13 14:00:00  20   10   20   10
8 2016-08-13 15:00:00  10   20   30   10
```

I would like to create a new dataframe `df2` in which I have the average water temperature per day for either each depth interval and for the whole water column and the standard error estimation. I would expect something like this (I did the calculations by hand so there might be some mistakes):

```
> df2
        Date meanT5m meanT15m meanT25m meanT35m meanTotal seT5m seT15m seT25m seT35m seTotal
1 2016-08-12      15       15     22.5       15    16.875  2.88   2.88    2.5   2.88    1.29
2 2016-08-13      15       15     22.5       15    16.875  2.88   2.88    2.5   2.88    1.29
```

I am especially interested in knowing how to do it with `data.table` since I will work with huge data.frames and I think `data.table` is quite efficient.

For calculating the standard error I know the function `std.error()` from the package `plotrix`.

Comment: check this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36527357/10580543 in your case you would summarise by Date and Depth interval instead of location

Comment: Thanks @tom. I don't get it very well... Do you know exactly which code should I write? Thanks!

Comment: I am not familiar enough with data.table to do so in the moment. But your question consists in groupping by and summarising the data, that the post I shared above do with data.table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update** based on @chinsoon's comment

---

1. First transform your data frame into a data table:

   ```
   library(data.table)
   setDT(df1)
   ```
2. Create a `total` column:

   ```
   df1[, total := rowSums(.SD), .SDcols = grep("T[0-9]+m", names(df1))][]
   #               Datetime T5m T15m T25m T35m total
   # 1: 2016-08-12 12:00:00  10   10   20   20    60
   # 2: 2016-08-12 13:00:00  20   20   20   20    80
   # 3: 2016-08-12 14:00:00  20   10   20   10    60
   # 4: 2016-08-12 15:00:00  10   20   30   10    70
   # 5: 2016-08-13 12:00:00  10   10   20   20    60
   # 6: 2016-08-13 13:00:00  20   20   20   20    80
   # 7: 2016-08-13 14:00:00  20   10   20   10    60
   # 8: 2016-08-13 15:00:00  10   20   30   10    70
   ```
3. Apply the functions per `day`:

   ```
   library(lubridate)
   (df3 <- df1[, as.list(unlist(lapply(.SD, function (x)
                c(mean = mean(x), sem = sd(x) / sqrt(length(x)))))), 
          day(Datetime)])
   #    day T5m.mean  T5m.sem T15m.mean T15m.sem T25m.mean T25m.sem T35m.mean
   # 1:  12       15 2.886751        15 2.886751      22.5      2.5        15
   # 2:  13       15 2.886751        15 2.886751      22.5      2.5        15
   #    T35m.sem total.mean total.sem
   # 1: 2.886751       67.5  4.787136
   # 2: 2.886751       67.5  4.787136
   ```

Comment: Hi @thothal, do you know why the `total` mean is wrong? It should be `16.875` instead of `67.5`. The mean represents the overall mean for the day considering the different depths and hours.

Comment: So in my example `total.mean` is the mean of column `total` that is the sum of all depth per `hour`. So I guess you should replace `rowSums` by  `rowMeans` in step 2.

Comment: you might want to see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29620783/apply-multiple-functions-to-multiple-columns-in-data-table/29621821#29621821 and the comments, hence `f <- function(x) c(mean=mean(x), sem=sd(x) / sqrt(length(x))); df1[, as.list(unlist(lapply(.SD, f))), by=mday(Datetime), .SDcols=T5m:T35m]`

Comment: @chinsoon: thanks very enlightening, updated my answer +1

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way using `dplyr` and `tidyr` calculated in two parts

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df2 <- df1 %>%
         mutate(Datetime = as.Date(Datetime)) %>%
         gather(key, value, -Datetime) %>%
         group_by(Datetime, key) %>%
         summarise(se = plotrix::std.error(value), 
                  mean = mean(value)) %>%
         gather(total, value, -key,  -Datetime) 


bind_rows(df2, df2 %>%  
                 group_by(Datetime, total) %>%
                 summarise(value = sum(value)) %>%
                 mutate(key = paste("total", c("mean", "se"), sep = "_"))) %>%
           unite(key, key, total) %>%
           spread(key, value) 


# A tibble: 2 x 11
# Groups:   Datetime [2]
#  Datetime   T15m_mean T15m_se T25m_mean T25m_se T35m_mean
#  <date>         <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>
#1 2016-08-12        15    2.89      22.5     2.5        15
#2 2016-08-13        15    2.89      22.5     2.5        15
# … with 5 more variables: T35m_se <dbl>, T5m_mean <dbl>,
#   T5m_se <dbl>, total_mean_mean <dbl>, total_se_se <dbl>
```

Comment: Thanks @Ronak Shah, do you know how to include also the mean considering all the depths?

Comment: @Dekike I have already included that in the calculation right? `summarise(se = plotrix::std.error(value), 
                  mean = mean(value))`

Comment: Sorry, I did't realize that there are 5 more columns hidden. I thought that what you showed was the final display with all the parameters. You are right!